# clang-tidy: Assigned value is garbage or undefined when accessing raw memory of an array or struct

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-tidy

When running clang-tidy I get an warning when accessing an address of an array:

```
src/main.cpp:10:9: warning: Assigned value is garbage or undefined [clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.Assign]
    sum += *(addr++);
        ^
```

The code is stripped down from a more complex example (full checksum implementation - taken from RFC1071 - and using a struct instead of the array):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

static uint16_t csum(void* buffer, size_t size)
{
  uint32_t sum = 0;
  auto *addr = static_cast<uint16_t *>(buffer);
  while( size > 1 )  {
    /*  This is the inner loop */
    sum += *(addr++);
    size -= sizeof(*addr);
  }
  return static_cast<uint16_t>(~sum);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  uint32_t test[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  //memset(&test, 0, sizeof(test));
  uint16_t sum = csum(test, sizeof(test));
  std::cout << argc << " " << argv[0] << " " << sum << " " << sizeof(test) << std::endl;
}
```

`clang-tidy` shows this `value is garbage or undefined` whenever the array is of type `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` (or using any custom packed struct) but not when being `uint16_t` or `uint8_t` - some alignment issue?

But at least for me more surprising - the warning is not shown with `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` or any custom packed struct when uncommenting the `memset` - why? Wasn't it proper initialized before? Do I hit some area, where C/C++ isn't defined properly?

Or will clang-tidy analyze every usage of `csum` - also those where the size of the `buffer` does not match the `size` variable?

Comment: Alignment issues should occur the other way around, if you feed in 1-byte aligned pointers into the pointer cast to `uint16_t`. You have to do that by `memcpy` into a temporary - don't worry about performance, the compiler will eliminate it and read it as "oh, that data *may* be misaligned".

Comment: Even though if you did pass in something like `struct { uint32_t; uint8_t; }` the warning would be valid due to the undefined padding bytes.

Comment: I originally used a struct with only uint16_t and uint8_t and used ```__attribute__((packed))``` - and got the same warning. But maybe the attribute just not checked by clang-tidy.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is technically correct for everything which isn't a `uint16_t`.

You can't just reinterpret-cast a pointer to some typed memory to another incompatible type. The result of that is undefined behavior and outside of whatever guarantees the C++ standard gives you. The only unexpected case here is that you haven't gotten a warning for the `uint_8` case, but I expect that's just a suppression to avoid false-positives in other use cases.

Why is that UB? Because you are making assumptions about memory layout beyond what's defined. Your code e.g. behaves entirely differently between little and big endian machines due to that cast.

You can get around that warning with the pattern:

```
uint8_t *src;
uint16_t tmp;
std::memcpy(&tmp, src, sizeof(tmp));
src += sizeof(tmp);
```

By which you don't perform any illegal casts, and actually claim all responsibility for the raw memory access.

Comment: I changed the cast to a ```uint64_t``` (and changed the code accordingly). So there was no warning for ```uint8_t```, ```uint16_t```, ```uint32_t``` and ```uint64_t``` - but the ```__attribute__((packed))``` struct still did not work.     Further more, when passing this struct by value (e.g. with a template method) the warning was gone - but passing it by ```const reference```, I got the same warning again.

Comment: Do you have an idea, why ```memset``` suppresses the warning?     Regarding the endianess: The checksum is intended for structs which have content in network byte-order - but clang-tidy cannot assume that.

Comment: `memset` probably just gives a hint to clang that you have explicitly set the memory contents, so it can't argue that you can't know the memory layout of "0" in the more complex type during the reinterpret cast.

Comment: The warning being gone when changing the cast target to something bigger makes no sense though...